# Is there an in-universe explanation for women's work clothing in Star Trek?

Tags: star-trek

Women's work clothing in Star Trek is something of a mixed bag. In TOS all the women wore the "skant", an extremely short dress with regulation division coloured panties and tights. TNG initially had skants too, but soon switched to gender neutral pyjamas.

On Voyager, Seven of Nine was given various catsuits, all very tight fitting and clearly designed to be appealing to the eye. On Enterprise, T'Pol was given similar catsuits to wear. While not members of Starfleet, they were members of their respective crews, and wore those clothes at work.

Discovery and Strange New Worlds offer Starfleet women more modest outfits. The SNW version of the skant is actually an undersuit, leggings, and a long jacket. It is also optional, with many women choosing the gender neutral version instead.

In the future everyone is fairly healthy, mostly not overweight, and living in a supposedly post-sexism, post-feminism society. Yet clothing for women is often rather provocative. It's even more problematic in the case of Seven, since she is at least initially unaware of how human relations work, having been Borg for most of her childhood when she would have learned about such things. If Trek society really was post-feminist, women and men would wear similarly practical work clothing, and be similarly expressive of their sexuality. For example, Seven's catsuits had no pockets and no utility belt to hang her tricorder off, as well as heels instead of boots. Why would anyone in a post-feminist world care about being a few centimetres taller anyway, especially Seven?

It's also notable that none of the male uniforms are similarly figure hugging. In TOS some of the men do go topless at times, but it's not part of their standard work garb. In TNG there were a couple of times when men were seen in skants. Also on TNG, Troi often wore "civilian" clothes to work, rather than a uniform, and many of those outfits had quite a bit of cleavage. An interesting choice for a healthcare professional.

Is there any in-universe explanation for, or discussion of this? Have any women (or men/non binary characters) commented on it?

The singular example I can think of is Jellico asking Troi to wear a standard uniform, but he doesn't really explain why beyond adherence to protocol.

Comment: An in-universe explanation is that they are a "post-" society, so your "pre-" society thoughts that "clothing for women is often rather provocative" are totally irrelevant.   Perhaps you are looking for an out of universe explanation of the costume design instead?

Comment: Star Trek as portrayed on screen is not really a post- society, there are numerous examples of sexism and differing standards for men and women... Such as their clothing. Maybe I can edit it to make that clearer.

Comment: It is striking how different the current standards in male and female dress are. People can do what they want but I am amazed at the percentage of exposed skin that is normal to be shown even at work for females; apparently this percentage even went up in the 24th century, at least if you were that week's love interest.

Comment: Work clothes in Trek tend not to show much skin, but for women they are tight fitting and arguably designed to be attractive in the case of TOS.

Comment: "Why would anyone in a post-feminist world care about being a few centimetres taller anyway, especially Seven?" — Keeping it in-universe, [The Doctor designed Seven's outfit](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Gift_(episode)#Act_Five), so its particulars may have been his choice, not hers. I can't remember if she ever expresses any preferences related to clothes. (She might have been somewhat preoccupied with trying to recover from decades of living as a Borg.)

Comment: Why would Jellico need to explain why, other than adherence to protocol?  Jellico is established as a by-the-book, possibly behind-the-times, old-school captain.  Fleet regs might *allow* Troi's casual-Friday-everyday dress, but as the commanding officer of the ship, he's well within his authority to insist on the uniform.

Comment: @user The point is that you are trying to apply your out-of-universe, 21st century viewpoint to a 23rd century, in-universe style.  You are claiming sexism, but in the process overlooking that in TOS (for starters) not only were there women in command positions, there were *black* women in command positions.  If you want to argue that the costume designs were demeaning to the actors, then that is a different question.

Comment: Come on, folks. We all know that (out-of-universe) Gene Roddenberry found women in revealing outfits attractive, but not men, and thus the differences in uniforms (other series followed his lead). It's not as if numerous actors from the series have not said as much.

Comment: I can't find it now but somewhere, probably memory alpha, are cast quotes about reuniting for TMP and Nichelle Nichols quote was basically complaining that TMP uniforms are bland compared to TOS.

Comment: "It's also notable that none of the male uniforms are similarly figure hugging." - now, does that mean they make the wearers less attractive than the female uniforms, or does it mean the opposite? I don't think "figure-hugging" and "attractive" are necessarily the same, and (saying this as a heterosexual male, so it is just a guess) quite some males look better (in terms of overall proportions) e.g. with some shoulder padding than without.

Comment: There is a (RL) school of thought that women are often more comfortable in revealing clothing and that any suggestion that such clothing is sexist is, itself, sexist. I have my own thoughts about where that idea comes from, but if it became widely accepted in the ST universe it would explain the oddities in uniform design.

Comment: The male uniforms are similarly figure-hugging though. Especially in early TNG. They had to be changed because they were injuring some of the actors.

Comment: @OrangeDog One of the reasons for changing the TOS costumes for the movies was that they thought the women's ones would have been considered sexist by the late 70s. They still managed to get Iliya into a skant though.

Comment: I wonder if Jellico would have insisted Seven change into a more formal outfit.

Comment: @HamSandwich correct me if I'm wrong but I don't think she was in Star Fleet until Picard season 3, where we see her in a standard uniform. On that note, I get that Shaw was supposed to be a bit of a dick, but you'd think that by that time not using people's preferred names would be unacceptable. Maybe it was a legal thing, but then why didn't Seven just change it?

Comment: I have no idea. I think STP is terrible.